# How to restore normal JTable row selection?; undo table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, locking, row

### Description

- At the beginning selecting a row using mouse click or keyboard arrows is possible with the selected row being colored with the normal row selection color.
- User can select single row.
- User can lock the selected row using code invoked by lock button. Locking itself is made possible by *imitating* a selected row (which I'm not sure if it is the proper way of doing so) and is done by two things:

  - Color the selected row using `DefaultTableCellRenderer`
  - Disable `JTable` row selection `setRowSelectionAllowed(false)`
- User can unlock/restore normal selection using code invoked by unlock button. Unlocking is simply to undo the steps of locking:

  - Remove coloring of the selected row using `DefaultTableCellRenderer`
  - Enable `JTable` row selection `setRowSelectionAllowed(true)` <-- (**does not work**)

How to restore normal `JTable` row selection?

### Code in [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) | [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) format

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableRowSelectionControl {

    private JButton btnJTableSelectionLocked;
    private JButton btnJTableSelectionUnlock;
    private JPanel panelControl;
    private JScrollPane scrollableTable;
    private Integer selectedId;
    private boolean lockedSelection;
    private Color rowSelectionColor;
    private Integer modelRow;
    private JTable table;
    private Object[][] data;

    private JPanel createPanel() {

        rowSelectionColor = new Color(184, 207, 229);
        btnJTableSelectionLocked = new JButton("Lock selected row");
        btnJTableSelectionLocked.setEnabled(false);
        btnJTableSelectionLocked.addActionListener(new BtnAction());

        btnJTableSelectionUnlock = new JButton("Unlock selection");
        btnJTableSelectionUnlock.setEnabled(false);
        btnJTableSelectionUnlock.addActionListener(new BtnAction());

        panelControl = new JPanel();
        panelControl.add(btnJTableSelectionLocked);
        panelControl.add(btnJTableSelectionUnlock);

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Id", "Name", "State"}, 0) {
            // Disable cell editing
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                // Disable cells editing.
                return false;
            }
        };

        data = new Object[][]{
            {1, "Alpha", true},
            {5, "Beta", false},
            {3, "Gama", true},
            {4, "Giga", true},
            {7, "Coca", true},};

        table = new JTable(model);
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(DefaultListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new RowSelectionListener());

        for (Object[] d : data) {
            model.addRow(d);
        }

        JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        containerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 200));

        scrollableTable = new JScrollPane(table);
        containerPanel.add(panelControl, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        containerPanel.add(scrollableTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return containerPanel;
    }

    private class RowSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {

            // Ensure single event invoked
            if (!event.getValueIsAdjusting() && !lockedSelection) {

                DefaultListSelectionModel selectionModel = (DefaultListSelectionModel) event.getSource();

                if (selectionModel.isSelectionEmpty()) {
                    // Empty selection: table row deselection occurred
                    btnJTableSelectionLocked.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    btnJTableSelectionLocked.setEnabled(true);
                    int viewRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                    if (viewRow > -1) {

                        int idsColumn = 0;
                        modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRow);
                        Object selectedIdObject = table.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, idsColumn);
                        selectedId = Integer.parseInt(selectedIdObject.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private DefaultTableCellRenderer getRowsColorRenderer(Integer selectedId) {

        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer;
        renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    JTable table,
                    Object value,
                    boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus,
                    int row,
                    int column) {
                Component tableCellRendererComponent
                        = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

                Integer id = (Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);

                if (selectedId != null && id.equals(selectedId)) {
                    setBackground(rowSelectionColor);
                    setForeground(table.getForeground());
                } else {
                    setBackground(table.getBackground());
                    setForeground(table.getForeground());
                }
                return tableCellRendererComponent;
            }
        };
        return renderer;
    }

    private class BtnAction implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Object btnClicked = e.getSource();
            int columnsSize = 3;

            if (btnClicked == btnJTableSelectionLocked) {
                lockedSelection = true;
                btnJTableSelectionLocked.setEnabled(false);
                btnJTableSelectionUnlock.setEnabled(true);
                table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false); // <-- Works fine.
                for (int i = 0; i < columnsSize; i++) {
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(getRowsColorRenderer(selectedId));
                }
            } else if (btnClicked == btnJTableSelectionUnlock) {
                lockedSelection = false;
                btnJTableSelectionLocked.setEnabled(true);
                btnJTableSelectionUnlock.setEnabled(false);
                table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true); // <-- This line does not restore normal selection
                for (int i = 0; i < columnsSize; i++) {
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(getRowsColorRenderer(null));
                }
                if (modelRow != null) {
                    // Enforce the same row to be selected on unloking;
                    // afterwords user can select any row.
                    table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, modelRow);
                }
            }
            table.repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            TableRowSelectionControl tableRowColorControl = new TableRowSelectionControl();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRowSelectionControl");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(tableRowColorControl.createPanel());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with you `TableCellRenderer`

The following...

```
Component tableCellRendererComponent
                    = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

//...

if (selectedId != null && id.equals(selectedId)) {
    setBackground(rowSelectionColor);
    setForeground(table.getForeground());
} else {
    setBackground(table.getBackground());
    setForeground(table.getForeground());
}
```

is overwriting the selection color made by the `super` call.

Instead, change it to...

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer;
renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus,
            int row,
            int column) {
        Component tableCellRendererComponent
                = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        Integer id = (Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);

        System.out.println("id = " + id + "; selectedId = " + selectedId + "; isSelected = " + isSelected);

        if (selectedId != null && id.equals(selectedId)) {
            setBackground(rowSelectionColor);
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
        } else if (!isSelected) {
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
        }
        return tableCellRendererComponent;
    }
};
```

One thing I might suggest is, instead of switching the cell renderer (which doesn't seem to be working), apply the cell renderer to the table and make use of the `put/getClientProperty` support of the `JTable`

```
private class BtnAction implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object btnClicked = e.getSource();
        int columnsSize = 3;

        if (btnClicked == btnJTableSelectionLocked) {
            System.out.println("Lock");
            lockedSelection = true;
            btnJTableSelectionLocked.setEnabled(false);
            btnJTableSelectionUnlock.setEnabled(true);
            table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false); // <-- Works fine.
            table.putClientProperty("selectedRowId", selectedId);
        } else if (btnClicked == btnJTableSelectionUnlock) {
            System.out.println("Unlock");
            lockedSelection = false;
            btnJTableSelectionLocked.setEnabled(true);
            btnJTableSelectionUnlock.setEnabled(false);
            table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true); // <-- This line does not restore normal selection
            table.putClientProperty("selectedRowId", null);
        }
    }
}
```

and...

```
public class LockableTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus,
            int row,
            int column) {
        Component tableCellRendererComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        Integer id = (Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
        Integer selectedId = (Integer) table.getClientProperty("selectedRowId");

        if (selectedId != null && id.equals(selectedId)) {
            setBackground(rowSelectionColor);
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
        } else if (!isSelected) {
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBorder(noFocusBorder);
        }
        return tableCellRendererComponent;
    }
}
```

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class Test {

    private JButton btnJTableSelectionLocked;
    private JButton btnJTableSelectionUnlock;
    private JPanel panelControl;
    private JScrollPane scrollableTable;
    private Integer selectedId;
    private boolean lockedSelection;
    private Color rowSelectionColor;
    private Integer modelRow;
    private JTable table;
    private Object[][] data;

    private JPanel createPanel() {

        rowSelectionColor = new Color(184, 207, 229);
        btnJTableSelectionLocked = new JButton("Lock selected row");
        btnJTableSelectionLocked.setEnabled(false);
        btnJTableSelectionLocked.addActionListener(new BtnAction());

        btnJTableSelectionUnlock = new JButton("Unlock selection");
        btnJTableSelectionUnlock.setEnabled(false);
        btnJTableSelectionUnlock.addActionListener(new BtnAction());

        panelControl = new JPanel();
        panelControl.add(btnJTableSelectionLocked);
        panelControl.add(btnJTableSelectionUnlock);

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Id", "Name", "State"}, 0) {
            // Disable cell editing
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                // Disable cells editing.
                return false;
            }
        };

        data = new Object[][]{
            {1, "Alpha", true},
            {5, "Beta", false},
            {3, "Gama", true},
            {4, "Giga", true},
            {7, "Coca", true},};

        table = new JTable(model);
        TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();

        LockableTableCellRenderer cellRenderer = new LockableTableCellRenderer();
        for (int column = 0; column < columnModel.getColumnCount(); column++) {
            columnModel.getColumn(column).setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
        }

        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(DefaultListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new RowSelectionListener());

        for (Object[] d : data) {
            model.addRow(d);
        }

        JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        containerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 200));

        scrollableTable = new JScrollPane(table);
        containerPanel.add(panelControl, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        containerPanel.add(scrollableTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return containerPanel;
    }

    private class RowSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {

            // Ensure single event invoked
            if (!event.getValueIsAdjusting() && !lockedSelection) {

                DefaultListSelectionModel selectionModel = (DefaultListSelectionModel) event.getSource();

                if (selectionModel.isSelectionEmpty()) {
                    // Empty selection: table row deselection occurred
                    btnJTableSelectionLocked.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    btnJTableSelectionLocked.setEnabled(true);
                    int viewRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                    if (viewRow > -1) {

                        int idsColumn = 0;
                        modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRow);
                        Object selectedIdObject = table.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, idsColumn);
                        selectedId = Integer.parseInt(selectedIdObject.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class BtnAction implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Object btnClicked = e.getSource();
            int columnsSize = 3;

            if (btnClicked == btnJTableSelectionLocked) {
                System.out.println("Lock");
                lockedSelection = true;
                btnJTableSelectionLocked.setEnabled(false);
                btnJTableSelectionUnlock.setEnabled(true);
                table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false); // <-- Works fine.
                table.putClientProperty("selectedRowId", selectedId);
            } else if (btnClicked == btnJTableSelectionUnlock) {
                System.out.println("Unlock");
                lockedSelection = false;
                btnJTableSelectionLocked.setEnabled(true);
                btnJTableSelectionUnlock.setEnabled(false);
                table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true); // <-- This line does not restore normal selection
                table.putClientProperty("selectedRowId", null);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Test tableRowColorControl = new Test();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRowSelectionControl");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(tableRowColorControl.createPanel());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public class LockableTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                JTable table,
                Object value,
                boolean isSelected,
                boolean hasFocus,
                int row,
                int column) {
            Component tableCellRendererComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            Integer id = (Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
            Integer selectedId = (Integer) table.getClientProperty("selectedRowId");

            if (selectedId != null && id.equals(selectedId)) {
                setBackground(rowSelectionColor);
                setForeground(table.getForeground());
            } else if (!isSelected) {
                setBackground(table.getBackground());
                setForeground(table.getForeground());
                setBorder(noFocusBorder);
            }
            return tableCellRendererComponent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; like a charm; I will adopt your suggestion. `put/getClientProperty` is a **new** concept to me. Does that mean when `put` is invoked, then somehow the table re-renders its content making use of the corresponding `get`?. Can you paste any resources (even from stackoverflow Q&A) to learn about it; *how does it work*, *how to implement such support/implementation in one's own classes*. I googled it but did not find useful stuff.

Comment: *"Does that mean when put is invoked..."* - No.  This is simply a means to associate a key/value pair with the given instance of component.  Oddly, it's not something that gets used alot

Answer (score 1):

Excelent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70441416/6811102) from MadProgrammer. Here I am only using it with little updates; for me as a reference and for future visitors.

- Instead of using some column value as unique identifier to track the selected row, use the `TableModel` row index; that is *row content agnostic* solution.
- When user unlocks the selected row; the same selected row is kept selected, for good user experience.

Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class TableRowSelectionControl {

    private JButton btnJTableSelectionLock;
    private JButton btnJTableSelectionUnlock;
    private JPanel panelControl;
    private JScrollPane scrollableTable;
    private boolean lockedSelection;
    private Color rowSelectionColor;
    private final String selectedRowKey = "selectedRow";
    private Integer selectedModelRow;
    private Integer oldSelectedModelRow;
    private JTable table;
    private Object[][] data;

    private JPanel createPanel() {

        rowSelectionColor = new Color(184, 207, 229);
        btnJTableSelectionLock = new JButton("Lock selected row");
        btnJTableSelectionLock.setEnabled(false);
        btnJTableSelectionLock.addActionListener(new BtnAction());

        btnJTableSelectionUnlock = new JButton("Unlock selection");
        btnJTableSelectionUnlock.setEnabled(false);
        btnJTableSelectionUnlock.addActionListener(new BtnAction());

        panelControl = new JPanel();
        panelControl.add(btnJTableSelectionLock);
        panelControl.add(btnJTableSelectionUnlock);

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Id", "Name", "State"}, 0) {
            // Disable cell editing
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                // Disable cells editing.
                return false;
            }
        };

        data = new Object[][]{
            {1, "Alpha", true},
            {5, "Beta", false},
            {3, "Gamma", true},
            {4, "Giga", true},
            {7, "Coca", true},};

        table = new JTable(model);
        TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();

        LockableTableCellRenderer cellRenderer = new LockableTableCellRenderer();
        for (int column = 0; column < columnModel.getColumnCount(); column++) {
            columnModel.getColumn(column).setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
        }

        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(DefaultListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new RowSelectionListener());

        for (Object[] d : data) {
            model.addRow(d);
        }

        JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        containerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 200));

        scrollableTable = new JScrollPane(table);
        containerPanel.add(panelControl, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        containerPanel.add(scrollableTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return containerPanel;
    }

    private class RowSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {

            // Ensure single event invoked
            if (!event.getValueIsAdjusting() && !lockedSelection) {

                DefaultListSelectionModel selectionModel = (DefaultListSelectionModel) event.getSource();

                if (selectionModel.isSelectionEmpty()) {
                    // Empty selection: table row deselection occurred
                    btnJTableSelectionLock.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    btnJTableSelectionLock.setEnabled(true);
                    int viewRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                    if (viewRow > -1) {
                        selectedModelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRow);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class BtnAction implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Object btnClicked = e.getSource();

            if (btnClicked == btnJTableSelectionLock) {
                System.out.println("Lock");
                lockedSelection = true;
                btnJTableSelectionLock.setEnabled(false);
                btnJTableSelectionUnlock.setEnabled(true);
                table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
                oldSelectedModelRow = selectedModelRow;
                table.putClientProperty(selectedRowKey, selectedModelRow);
            } else if (btnClicked == btnJTableSelectionUnlock) {
                System.out.println("Unlock");
                lockedSelection = false;
                btnJTableSelectionLock.setEnabled(true);
                btnJTableSelectionUnlock.setEnabled(false);
                table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
                table.putClientProperty(selectedRowKey, null);
                table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, oldSelectedModelRow);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            TableRowSelectionControl tableRowColorControl = new TableRowSelectionControl();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRowSelectionControl");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(tableRowColorControl.createPanel());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public class LockableTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                JTable table,
                Object value,
                boolean isSelected,
                boolean hasFocus,
                int row,
                int column) {
            Component tableCellRendererComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            Integer renderedRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
            Integer selectedRow = (Integer) table.getClientProperty(selectedRowKey);

            if (selectedRow != null && renderedRow.equals(selectedRow)) {
                setBackground(rowSelectionColor);
                setForeground(table.getForeground());
            } else if (!isSelected) {
                setBackground(table.getBackground());
                setForeground(table.getForeground());
                setBorder(noFocusBorder);
            }
            return tableCellRendererComponent;
        }
    }
}
```